In Lafont's interaction net, how to prevent undesirable annihilation?
Here is a simple case, given function f and input x, compute y = f(f(x)):
this can be translated to interaction net:
------->

x      y
: .... |
\ /  \ /
 :    :
 :....:
   f

using rule of annihilation, we get:
------->

x      y
: .... |
: :  : :
: :..:.:
:....:

------->

x .... y

the result is y = x, a very trivial special case that the original computation may or may not satisfy (depending on if it has fixed point)
How to prevent it from happening?

I believe sequent calculus has a similar problem related to weakening, (weakening can't be strongly normalising as key information will be lost), there should be a special rule or EqSat method to prevent this from happening

Why do you connect the two bottom ports? Shouldn't you connect the bottom port of the left node with the left port of the right node?

which version of Interaction net do you use? (I used https://youtu.be/_uIGQ1biCXY?t=48) Also do you mean auxiliary port?

No, the bottom ports are meant to be the principal port, right?

This simply looks like a mistranslation. What translation procedure are you following?

it is here: https://github.com/victortaelin/interaction-calculus. both function applications becomes \ / constructors, where input & output are auxiliary ports

Well then why are you connecting the two principal ports? According to the translation, since f appears twice, there must be a duplication node whose two auxiliary ports connect to the two principal ports you draw, and the principal port of it connect to the definition of f.
